# Initial value problem with $t$ and $x'$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Really stuck with this,

\begin{cases}
 2tx'(t)-1=x^2t \\
 x(t=1)=1 \\
 \end{cases}

I don't understand the variables. What does it mean that $x$ differentiated have $t$ as a function value, like this: $x'(t)$? Don't get it :(

Comment: $x'(t)$ means that $x$ is a function of $t$ which has been differentiated with respect to $t$.

Comment: Your first equation is really $2t x'(t) -1= (x(t))^2 t$.

Comment: This notation implies that $x$ is a function of $t$, so think of $x$ as the output value on the vertical axis, where $y$ usually is, and $t$ as the input value on the horizontal axis, where $x$ usually is.

Comment: Another way to write the first one is: $$2t\frac{dx}{dt} - 1 = x^2t$$.

Comment: $$x'(t)=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{x(t+h)-x(t)}{h}$$

Answer (score 1):

One way to see it simply is :

**Find all the solutions of functions** $x : t \to x(t) $ **such that**

$$ \forall t \in [1, \infty[, \ 2tx'(t)-1=x^2(t)t\\
x(1)=1$$

The defintion domain is here at minima (it can be bigger than $[1,\infty[$)

Comment: Thank you. So is it then a first order DE?

Comment: It is indeed a first order non linear differential equation :)

Answer (score 0):

$x'(t)$ simply means the derivative of the function $x$ with respect to $t$. It means exactly the same thing as
$$\frac{dx}{dt}$$

Comment: This is not *quite* right. $x'(t)$ is the function $x'$, evaluated at the argument $t$. $dx/dt$ is simply the function you get when you differentiate $x$ with respect to its argument. The most technically correct way to write this would be $$x'(t)=\frac{dx}{dt}(t)$$ This is why I prefer to use differential operator notation: $$\mathrm{D}_t(x)(t)$$

Comment: @K.defaoite I don;t really see the difference; any derivative of function of  a parameter is evaluated at that parameter is it not? eg for $f(x)=x^2$ then $f'(x)=2x$ is evaluated at $x$.

Comment: $f(x)$ is not a function. $f:x\mapsto f(x)$ is.